# Mock a node module using jest with relative paths react

Tags: jestjs, mocking

I have installed a node module called **@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary.** It is being imported in source code in multiple ways in multiple files. For example,

```
import { SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_MODULE1} from "@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary/Module1"
 import {SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_SUB_MODULE} from  "@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary/Module1/SubModule"    
import {SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_MODULE2} from "@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary/Module2"
```

etc.

How can I mock the `@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary` using JEST so that it would work correctly on each file's test cases? Actually, I have tried the following way to mock it in a file and added it to the setupFiles key in the JEST config.

```
jest.mock("@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary", () => ({
 Module1: {  
   SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_MODULE1: jest.fn(), 
      SubModule: {
        SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_SUB_MODULE: jest.fn() 
                 }     
          }, 
 Module2: {
   SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_MODULE2: jest.fn()
          } 
 ))
```

But it is not working. Please suggest me a generic way so that it would work for all relative paths imported from a node module.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for the above scenario. But this is not an optimal one. Edits are welcome.

```
 1. module1_mock.js
jest.mock('@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary/Module1', () => {
return {
 SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_MODULE1: jest.fn()
}
})
 2. sub_module_mock.js
jest.mock('@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary/Module1/SubModule', () => {
return {
  SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_SUB_MODULE: jest.fn()
}
})
 3. module2_mock.js
 jest.mock('@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary/Module2', () => {
  return {
SOME_IMPORTS_FROM_MODULE2: jest.fn()
 }
})
 4. module_mock.js
 jest.mock('@SomeOrg/SomeLibrary', () => {
  return {
     __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(),
  }
 })
```

Once the above files are created, add them to the setupFiles key inside the jest configuration file like below.

```
{
...defaultConfig,
setupFiles: ["DIRECTORY_OF_MOCKS/module1_mock.js","DIRECTORY_OF_MOCKS/sub_module_mock.js","DIRECTORY_OF_MOCKS/module2_mock.js","DIRECTORY_OF_MOCKS/module_mock.js"]
}
```